# ICE Servers in Kurento Doesn't Work in an Example Behind a NAT

Tags: webrtc, kurento

My post is about WebRTC Recording tutorial from Kurento documentation.

I have already configured STUN and TURN servers as per instructions in [here](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_guide.html) in WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini.

I don't know why in [here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js/blob/master/kurento-recorder/js/index.js#L34) the ice_servers is set to "undefined". As per instructions from Kurento PDF documentation page 357, I got a free access numb STUN/TURN server from numb.viagenie.ca and now this line is like following:

```
ice_servers: [{"urls":"turn:numb.viagenie.ca","username":"testuserabc@gmail.com","credential":"Password"}]
```

But still the ICE Server is not working and I can't get the example tutorial working behind a NAT server. It works perfectly fine in a local machine.

Can you please help me in this regards, already spent several days?

Comment: Looks like `undefined` is just the default value they chose. Can you provide more of your source code and log files?

Comment: undefined is chosen for running the example on a local machine, but when it is behind a NAT, you have to have a STUN/TURN server. My code is exactly the same as shared in my problem (on github).

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of hustle, finally I found that my certificate.pem didn't contain private key.

If you had the same problem, make sure that you have the certificate and private key in the certificate.pem file that you will give it to:

```
/etc/kurento/kurento.conf.json
```